# "The feminine expressions could be spotted in ewes" - what does it mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you explain following phrase please?:

> The feminine expressions could be spotted in ewes due to female hormones but not in male sheep.

Dictionaries have too much meanings for "to spot" and I have no idea which one fits here.

Here are links to the sources:

- http://www.stepbystep.com/difference-between-ewe-and-sheep-100060/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPAG4-YFszM

**Update**

I was falsely interpreting *feminine expressions* as *words* rather than *facial expressions*.

Comment: What steps have you taken so far to determine its meaning?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include this to avoid people downvoting/closevoting it for lack of research? Please include what you found and why it didn't help you, and I'll be happy to post an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'll delete the ones in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, [***spot***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spot) is being used in its meaning of

> to ​see or ​notice someone or something, usually because you are ​looking hard
>
> *Cambridge English Dictionary*

The sentence is saying that they were able to notice feminine facial features (expressions) in ewes, but could not see them in male sheep, as ewes have female hormones and male sheep do not.

Comment: @Paul Yes, link the video and article into your question. The question should stand on its own in relation to research and context for the sake of people who read the question later.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a medical text describing the effect of the hormones on the animals' faces (leading to the appearance of spots, i.e. dots), the root word *spot* in "could be spotted in" would normally be read to mean *noticed*.

> **Spot** *verb*
>   1 See, notice, or recognize (someone or something) that is difficult to detect or that one is searching for: *Andrew spotted the advert in the paper*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spot)

The term *feminine expression* is related to the effect that the *female hormones* have on the animals. The natural reading of your quote is that the female hormones make ewes look feminine, but they don't make the male sheep look feminine.

Answer (score 0):

***Spot*** has very many possible meanings.

In this context, 'spotted' means 'noticed' or 'observed', as in [definition #22 of ***Spot*** from TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spot):

> *to observe or perceive suddenly, esp under difficult circumstances; discern*

This relates to other usages, such the (frequently military) role of 'spotter':  'One that looks for, locates, and reports something' ([TheFreeDictionary, again](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spotter)).